# Initial Check-In with TF.exe

Tags: batch-file, tf-cli

I am trying to checkin a few files, that weren't added to the TFS yet. Is that possible?

My current batch script is able to update already existant files:

```
set USER=%1
set PASS=%2

"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"
      checkin /comment:"PackagesCheckin" /noprompt /recursive 
              /override:"PackageCheckin" "$/Test/InstallPackages"
```

Unfortunately it does not work for files, that haven't been added yet.

1. Is it possible to add new files, that haven't been checked in yet?
2. Can you specify types, e.g. only checkin files with a *.png-extension?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" /?
```

and observe the "tf add" command. That is what you need.